# How do I get the current value of a Variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose we have a variable:

```
x = tf.Variable(...)
```

This variable can be updated during the training process using the `assign()` method.

*What is the best way to get the current value of a variable?*

I know we could use this:

```
session.run(x)
```

But I'm afraid this would trigger a whole chain of operations.

In Theano, you could just do

```
y = theano.shared(...)
y_vals = y.get_value()
```

I'm looking for the equivalent thing in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In general, `session.run(x)` will evaluate only the nodes that are necessary to compute `x` and nothing else, so it should be relatively cheap if you want to inspect the value of the variable.

Take a look at this great answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33610914/5543198 for more context.

Answer (score 40):

The only way to get the value of the variable is by running it in a `session`. In the [FAQ it is written](http://tensorflow.org/resources/faq.md#contents) that:

> A Tensor object is a symbolic handle to the result of an operation,
>   but does not actually hold the values of the operation's output.

So TF equivalent would be:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    v = sess.run(x)
    print(v)  # will show you your variable.
```

The part with `init = global_variables_initializer()` is important and should be done in order to initialize variables.

Also, take a look at [InteractiveSession](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession) if you work in IPython.

Comment: And to be very clear:  Running the variable will produce only the current value of the variable;  it will *not* run any assign operations associated with it.  It's cheap.

Comment: @dga yes, if the variable depends on n other variables, they also need to be evaluated. If you want to get the value of many, you do: `a, b = sess.run([v1, v2])`

Answer (score 17):

`tf.Print` can simplify your life!

`tf.Print` will print the value of the tensor(s) you tell it to print at the moment where the `tf.Print` line is called in your code when your code is evaluated.

So for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
x = tf.Print(x,[x])
x = 2* x

tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run()
```

> [1.0 2.0 ]

because it prints the value of `x` at the moment when the `tf.Print` line is. If instead you do

```
v = x.eval()
print(v)
```

you will get:

> [2.0 4.0 ]

because it will give you the final value of x.

Answer (score 1):

As they cancelled `tf.Variable()` in `tensorflow 2.0.0`,

If you want to extract values from a `tensor(ie "net")`, you can use this,

```
net.[tf.newaxis,:,:].numpy().
```