# How to convert tensorflow variable to a python variable?

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow

I have a variable naming decoder. At the beginning it is a python array. Then it is assigned to a tensor for further computation and after the computation is done, I want to see the real value of this array again. How is it possible?
By writing `tf.Print(value)` or `print(value)` I get something like below:

```
<tf.Tensor 'decoder1:0' shape=(?,) dtype=int32>
```

And also by writing `tf.get_variable("decoder1:0",0)` I get this at the console: `tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7fe5000deb50>`

How can I see the inside value of this variable?

p.s. I also have seen other posts in SO like this one: [TensorFlow - get current value of a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679382/tensorflow-get-current-value-of-a-variable) and etc. but none helped me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to evaluate the tensor variable:

```
p_value = sess.run(value)
```

If you have a default session:

```
p_value = value.eval()
```