# How to save tensorflow specific variable to local disk as a ndarray?(not layer parameter,just a variable, or tensor)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

How to save tensorflow specific variable to local disk as a ndarray?(not layer parameter,just a variable, or tensor)
Like :

```
ux=tf.Variable([10,1600,1,2])

tf.save('ux.npy',ux)
```

Is there anything like the code above? And after that I can load the ux.npy like:

```
ux = numpy.load('ux.npy')
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679382/tensorflow-get-current-value-of-a-variable) and then you can save the numpy array that you get from it

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has save and load function itself so for saving the numpy array you can use its function. The syntax is:

```
numpy.savetxt(Out_file_name, numpy_to_save)
```

Comment: why this error :   >>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ux=tf.Variable([10,1600,1,2])
>>> np.savetxt('ux.npy',ux)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jcc/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1118, in savetxt
    ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>>

Comment: can you try save instead of savetxt?