# Tensorflow - assertion failed: [predictions must be in [0, 1]]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the `Estimator` API of Tensorflow and I am running into the following problem. I want to check the f1 score other than the accuracy and when I am evaluating after training there are no problems at all, when I am testing it asks for normalized values, which I have already normalized.

This is the model of my of the network (first part is omitted):

```
#### architecture omitted #####

predictions = {
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
        "probabilities": tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), logits=tf.cast(logits, tf.float32), name="sigmoid_tensor")
}


if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=labels, logits=logits)

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    #optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.96)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
                              loss=loss,
                              global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook({"loss" : loss}, every_n_iter=10)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, training_hooks = [logging_hook])


eval_metric_ops = {
    "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
    labels=tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1),
    predictions=predictions["classes"]),

    "f1 score" : tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score(
    labels = tf.argmax(input=labels, axis=1),
    predictions = tf.cast(predictions["classes"],tf.float32)/tf.norm(tf.cast(predictions["classes"], tf.float32)))
}

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

This is the training script I am using, I don't have any problems when evaluating (no errors here).

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=instrument_recognition_model, model_dir=saved_model_path)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=16, num_epochs=30, shuffle=True)
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)

# Evaluate results on the training set
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x=X_eval,y=y_eval,num_epochs=1,shuffle=False)
eval_results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print(eval_results)
```

This is my testing script, here the program fails:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=instrument_recognition_model, model_dir=saved_model_path)

# Keep only certain samples
key_indices = [np.where(instruments == x)[0][0] for x in keys]
example_indices = np.array([])
for ind in key_indices:
    tmp = np.argwhere(labels[:,ind] == True).flatten()
    example_indices = np.union1d(example_indices, tmp).astype(np.int32)

features = features[example_indices].astype(np.float32)
example_indices = [[x for i in key_indices] for x in example_indices]
labels = labels[example_indices, key_indices].astype(np.int)

# Evaluate results on the test set
print(features)
print(labels)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x=features, y=labels, batch_size=1, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
eval_results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print(eval_results)
```

I have really not idea of what's wrong since I've follwed the same process for evaluation and testing. Without the f1 metric (only accuracy) everything works well, when I add the f1 metric, it fails in the test script.

The fragment of the error is the following:

```
### trace error omitted ###
File "../models.py", line 207, in instrument_recognition_model
    predictions = tf.cast(predictions["classes"],tf.float32)/tf.norm(tf.cast(predictions["classes"], tf.float32)))
### trace error ommitted ###

    TheInvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [predictions must be in [0, 1]] [Condition x <= y did not hold element-wise:x (div:0) = ] [nan] [y (f1/Cast_1/x:0) = ] [1]
         [[Node: f1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](f1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch, f1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, f1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_1, f1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1, f1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_3, f1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_2)]]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Because your data is probably multi-class. If you check official docs of f1-score of Tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/f1_score), you can see that it is implemented for binary classification only.
You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960730/1430342) if you really want f1-score.