# Calculate F1 Score using tf.metrics.precision/recall in a tf.Estimator setup

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to calculate F1 score in a `tf.Estimator` setup.

I've seen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365007/tensorflow-precision-recall-f1-score-and-confusion-matrix), but couldn't distill a working solution from it.

The thing with `tf.Estimator` is that it expects me to deliver a value and an update op, so right now, I have this piece of code at the end of my model:

```
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    with tf.variable_scope('eval'):
        precision, precision_update_op = tf.metrics.precision(labels=labels,
                                            predictions=predictions['class'],
                                            name='precision')

        recall, recall_update_op = tf.metrics.recall(labels=labels,
                                      predictions=predictions['class'],
                                      name='recall')

        f1_score, f1_update_op = tf.metrics.mean((2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall), name='f1_score')

        eval_metric_ops = {
            "precision": (precision, precision_update_op),
            "recall": (recall, recall_update_op),
            "f1_score": (f1_score, f1_update_op)}
```

Now the precision and recall seem to be working just fine, but on the F1 score, I keep getting `nan`.

How should I go about getting this to work?

EDIT:

A working solution can be achieved with `tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score` but since `contrib` is going to be deprecated in TF 2.0, I'd appreciate a `contrib`-less solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TensorFlow addons](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons) already has an official solution

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score

Answer (score 1):

I did it in this way:

```
def f1_score_class0(labels, predictions):
    """
    To calculate f1-score for the 1st class.
    """
    prec, update_op1 = tf.compat.v1.metrics.precision_at_k(labels, predictions, 1, class_id=0)
    rec,  update_op2 = tf.compat.v1.metrics.recall_at_k(labels, predictions, 1, class_id=0)

    return {
            "f1_Score_for_class0":
                ( 2*(prec * rec) / (prec + rec) , tf.group(update_op1, update_op2) )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Why are you doing `tf.metrics.mean`? recall and precision are scalar values

2) have you tried printing `f1_score` and `f1_update_op`?

3) From the [documentation of recall](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/recall) they mention how

> For estimation of the metric over a stream of data, the function creates an update_op that updates these variables and returns the recall. update_op weights each prediction by the corresponding value in weights

Since you're getting the F1-score directly from the two ops that handle the updating, try doing a tf.identity (which effectively causes no change)

Comment: You can't do that, because the `eval_metric_ops` expect to get a tuple of `(value, update_op)`

Comment: Yeah, so the first value is the f1_score as you've calculated, and the second op is just the identity op?

Answer (score 0):

The f1 value tensor can be computed from precision and recall values. The metrics must be (value, update_op) tuples. We can pass tf.identity for f1. This worked for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def metric_fn(labels, logits):
    predictions = tf.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    pr, pr_op = tf.metrics.precision(labels, predictions)
    re, re_op = tf.metrics.recall(labels, predictions)
    f1 = (2 * pr * re) / (pr + re)
    return {
        'precision': (pr, pr_op),
        'recall': (re, re_op),
        'f1': (f1, tf.identity(f1))
    }
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the `tf.identity(f1)` where the op is expected?

Comment: It converts a Tensor to a dummy Operation since the tf.metrics must return tuple (value Tensor, update Operation).

Comment: Are you sure this works? from my understanding the op is used for the ability to calculate the metric in batches, since here the op doesn't have any meaning, I wonder if it doesn't corrupt the score