# How to compute f1 in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, model, metrics

I have a code which computes the accuracy, but now i want to compute the f1 score.

```
accuracy_1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(
    tf.argmax(output_1, axis=-1),
    tf.argmax(y_1, axis=-1)), tf.float32), name="accuracy_1")
accuracy_2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(
    tf.argmax(output_2, axis=-1),
    tf.argmax(y_2, axis=-1)), tf.float32), name="accuracy_2")
```

How to compute f1 equivalent for the above code. I'm finding it difficult as i am very new to tensorflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365007/tensorflow-precision-recall-f1-score-and-confusion-matrix

Comment: Sorry, its not. I want a code equivalent to compute F1.