# How to print the value of a tensor in tensorflow mnist_softmax.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just tried to run `mnist_softmax.py` in TensorFlow 0.8.
I want to observe the value of `y` and `y_` just before the model test step.

Below is the code:

```
print(y)  # added by me
print(y_)  # added by me

# Test trained model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
```

The completed code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py).

Below is the output:

```
Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32)
```

I have also tried to use  `sess.run(y)`,  and  `y.eval()`, but I get an error like this when I try it:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
         [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'Placeholder', defined at: ...
```

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610685/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-session-run-and-tensor-eval/33610914#33610914

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Both the `y` and `y_` tensors depend on [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder) operations, and so they require you to *feed* an input value when you evaluated them. You can print the output of the softmax on a batch of input data by feeding a batch of input like so:

```
batch_xs, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
print(y.eval({x: batch_xs}))
```

---

The MNIST example contains the following lines:

```
# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
```

Note that the first tensor you are trying to print, `y`, is a function of `x`, which is defined as a `tf.placeholder()`. The `tf.placeholder()` op is a way of defining a symbolic [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function) to the computation: it doesn't have any value itself, but instead it says that `x` must be a matrix of floating-point values with `784` columns.

Running/evaluating `y` without providing a value for `x` is like writing the following Python function and calling it without all of its arguments:

```
def y(x):
    W = ...
    b = ...
    return softmax(matmul(x, W), b)

# This would fail with an error.
print(y())
```

How do you specify a value for the argument? In TensorFlow, you do this by *feeding* a value for the placeholder (like in the [training loop](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f8eb1d70a7ea7dc2cd5e1eddde389395f88a6be9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py#L53) and [accuracy calculation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f8eb1d70a7ea7dc2cd5e1eddde389395f88a6be9/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py#L58)):

```
# Get a batch of input data to feed to the computation.
batch_xs, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch_xs}))
# or
print(y.eval({x: batch_xs}))
```

The tensor `y_` is *defined as* a `tf.placeholder()`. For technical reasons, you can't evaluate a placeholder directly, even if you feed a value for it. However, it wouldn't be particularly useful to do this! Instead, you can just print the value that you would have fed.

Comment: Thank you, mrry. I was troubled by this problem for a whole day. Your explanation is much more clear than tensorflow.org.