# Is necessary to use to both eval and run?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I understood the difference between the two from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610685/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-session-run-and-tensor-eva).
But in most talks/code online I find people using both as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.constant(5.0)
b=tf.constant(6.0)
c=a*b
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))
    print(c.eval())
```

I don't understand the need and utility for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `sess.run(c)` and `c.eval()`, in the same session, provide exactly the same results.

You can mix calls to `sess.run` and `<tensor>.eval()` in the code, but it makes your code less consistent.

In my opinion, it's better to use always `sess.run`, beacuse within a single call you can evaluate more then one tensor.

Instead, if you use `<tensor>.eval()` you can evaluate **only** the specified `<tensor>`.

You can see the performance differences running this script:

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf

a=tf.constant(5.0)
b=tf.constant(6.0)
c=a*b

start = time.time()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([c]*100)
end_run = time.time() - start

start = time.time()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(100):
        c.eval()
end_eval = time.time() - start

print('Run: {}\nEval: {}'.format(end_run, end_eval))
```

Running it with Tensorflow r0.11, on CPU (Intel i3) it gives this result:

```
Run: 0.009401798248291016
Eval: 0.021142005920410156
```

As you can see, the execution of a `sess.run` call with a list of 100 elements is much fast then the execution of 100 `c.eval()` calls.

In fact, Tensorflow evaluates only once the `c` tensor in the `sess.run` call, and reuse the result to do other computation if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to your question is **NO**.

You just need either `Session.run()` or `Tensor.eval()` to evaluate the value of a tensor object. People usually use `Tensor.eval()` to experiment the programming model, namely print out the value of tensors to track the flow! For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1, 2], name='a')
b = tf.constant([3, 4], name='b')
c = tf.constant([1, 3], name='c')

d = tf.add_n([a, b])
e = tf.pow(d, c)

printout_d = tf.Print(d, [a, b, d], 'Input for d and the result: ')
printout_e = tf.Print(e, [d, c, e], 'Input for e and the result: ')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([d, e])
    printout_d.eval()
    printout_e.eval()
```

In the above code, you can simply need `sess.run([d, e])` to execute the graph. But, in some cases, for example debugging, you can benefit from `printout_d.eval()` and `printout_e.eval()`.