# Tensorflow: Is it always more convenient to use InteractiveSession() compared to Session()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems to be more convenient to simply use something like `sub.eval()` instead of `sess.run(eval)`, so would it be more convenient to always use `InteractiveSession()`? Are there any tradeoffs if we were to use `InteractiveSession()` all the time?

So far the only 'disadvantage' I see is that I can't use something like:

```
with tf.InteractiveSession() as sess:
   result = product.eval() #Where product is a simple matmul
   print result
   sess.close()
```

Instead I've to just define `sess = tf.InteractiveSession` right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their implementation, the `InteractiveSession` sets itself as the default session and your subsequent `eval()` calls can use this session. You should be able to use the `InteractiveSession` in almost all the cases where you use `Session`.

One small difference is that you don't need to use `InteractiveSession` in a `with` block:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# do your work
sess.close()
```

So don't forget to close the session after doing your work.

Here is an comparison between `session.run()` and `eval()`: [In TensorFlow, what is the difference between Session.run() and Tensor.eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610685/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-session-run-and-tensor-eval)