# Tensorflow Value Error : Cannot evaluate tensor using eval

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and getting Tensorflow value error with following script :

```
 W = tf.Variable(10)
 print(W.eval())
```

Also I tried thisway :

`with Session() as sess:
        print(W.eval())`

It throws error of unitialized value Variable.

Now when I am declaring `W = tf.Variable(10)` isn't it going to initialize it with 10 ?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

> When you launch the graph, variables have to be explicitly
>   initialized before   you can run Ops that use their value. You can
>   initialize a variable by   running its *initializer op*, restoring the
>   variable from a save file, or   simply running an `assign` Op that
>   assigns a value to the variable. In fact,   the variable *initializer
>   op* is just an `assign` Op that assigns the   variable's initial value
>   to the variable itself.
>
> ```
>  # Launch the graph in a session.   
>  with tf.Session() as sess:
>     # Run the variable initializer.
>     sess.run(w.initializer)
>     # ...you now can run ops that use the value of 'w'...
> ```
>
> The most common initialization pattern is to use the convenience function
>     `global_variables_initializer()` to add an Op to the graph that initializes
>     all the variables. You then run that Op after launching the graph.
>
> ```
>  # Add an Op to initialize global variables.
>   init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()   
>   # Launch the graph in a session.
>   with tf.Session() as sess:
>       # Run the Op that initializes global variables.
>       sess.run(init_op)
>       # ...you can now run any Op that uses variable values...
> ```

as a result you need to use something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf  
W = tf.Variable(10)
print('W: {0}'.format(W))
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(W.initializer)
    print(W.eval())
```

FYI [In TensorFlow, what is the difference between Session.run() and Tensor.eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33610914/395857)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly run an initializer operation

```
sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(W))
```

before evaluating any nodes which are dependent on W.

Answer (score 0):

Another example,

```
    import tensorflow as tf  
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([700,10]))
   sess = tf.Session()
   with sess.as_default():
        sess.run(W.initializer)
        print(W.eval())
```

result:

```
[[-0.3294761   0.6800459   1.33331    ...  1.42762    -1.3164878
   1.4831722 ]
 [-1.0402402   0.52254885 -1.344712   ... -0.30849338  0.15020785
   1.6682776 ]
 [-1.1791034   1.4859517  -1.7137778  ...  0.844212    1.5928217
  -0.21043983]
 ...
 [ 0.01982834 -1.1290654   0.33557415 ...  0.0510614  -0.6524679
   0.16643837]
 [-0.09969945 -0.10285325 -1.1134144  ...  1.2253191   0.13343143
  -1.7491579 ]
 [-1.9345136   0.63447094  1.1200713  ...  0.5357313   1.8579113
   0.8549472 ]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.