# How to print weights in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get the weight matrix of my hidden_layer2 and print it.
It seems like I am able to get the weight matrix, but I am not able to print it.

When using `tf.Print(w, [w])` it prints nothing.
When using `print(tf.Print(w,[w])` it prints at least the info about the tensor:

```
Tensor("hidden_layer2_2/Print:0", shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32)
```

I also tried to use `tf.Print()` outside of the **with**-Statement, same result.

Full code is here, I am just processing random data in a feed-forward NN: https://pastebin.com/KiQUBqK4

A part of my Code:

```
hidden_layer2 = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=hidden_layer1,
        units=2,
        activation=tf.nn.relu,
        name="hidden_layer2")


with tf.variable_scope("hidden_layer2", reuse=True):
        w = tf.get_variable("kernel")
        tf.Print(w, [w])
        # Also tried tf.Print(hidden_layer2, [w])
```

Comment: Did you run the graph afterwards? `tf.Print()` is another OP on the graph, which doesn't execute until you evaluate the graph. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33633370/826970).

Comment: I think I did, since the net produced an output.
I used tf.app.run() to run my whole main function.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATED FOR TENSORFLOW 2.X**

Starting from TensorFlow 2.0 (>= 2.0), since the `Session` object has been removed and the recommended high-level backend is Keras, the way to do get the weights is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2

model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=[128, 128, 3], include_top=False) #or whatever model
print(model.layers[0].get_weights()[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are multiple issues to be tackled here.

1. Running eval() should be accompanied by a session. As suggested in [In TensorFlow, what is the difference between Session.run() and Tensor.eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610685/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-session-run-and-tensor-eval), `.eval()` expects a default session to be running which was not likely in your case earlier. So, the best option here was to precede the code with a session. From your comment, we can see that this is done.
2. The variables in the hidden layers (i.e. weights/kernels) need to be initialized once the graph is complete. Hence, you might want to use something similar to this:

   ```
   init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
   sess = tf.Session()
   sess.run(init)
   with tf.variable_scope("hidden_layer2", reuse=True):
       w = tf.get_variable("kernel")
       print(w.eval(session=sess))
   ```

Comment: I also think it is better to print a tensor anywhere outside the function using its name. Existing tensors in the graph can be obtained using `[node.name for node in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]`
 and print the tensor `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("<<some tensor name>>:<<its index>>").eval(session=<<session name>>)` for e.g.  `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("const:0").eval(session=sess)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this,

```
w = tf.get_variable("kernel")
print(w.eval())
```

Comment: Eval does not work for me. If I use your code it says "no default session registered, use eval(session=sess)", if I create a session and pass it to eval, it says "Attempting to use uninitialized value hidden_layer2/kernel"

Comment: try this
import tensorflow as tf  ;
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  ;

a = tf.print(w,[w]) ;
print(a.eval()) ;

#I have used semicolon to show a new line as it is a comment

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is also not working. It says the layer, from which I want to get the weights, is not initialized yet. Maybe I need to run it somewhere else. I added the full code to my question.

Comment: I hope that someone more qualified answer and help you soon. :) Good luck. and if you find a solution please do mention here. :)

Comment: Ok, I did not found any other working solution. I switched now to keras, there it works in seconds and without a problem like this for the weights of layer 0 in your model: layer0 = model.layers[0]; weights = layer0.get_weights()[0];

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach. First I list all the trainable variables and use the index of the required variable and run it using the current session. The code is attached below:

```py
variables = tf.trainable_variables()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print("Weight matrix: {0}".format(sess.run(variables[0])))  # For me the variable at the 0th index was the one I required
```

Answer (score 0):

An example on how to print weights per layer in `tensorflow.js`:

```
// 
const model = tf.sequential();
...

// kernel:
model.layers[0].getWeights()[0].print()

// bias:
model.layers[0].getWeights()[1].print()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an update to Timbus Calin answer in Tensorflow 2, biases can be accessed also using `get_weights()`, specifically `get_weights()[1]`.

To access and print weights and biases for example in feedforward network:

```
for layer in self.model.layers:
      print(layer.get_weights()[0]) # weights
      print(layer.get_weights()[1]) # biases
```