# Why is call called twice during model.fit

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x=np.random.rand(20,10,64)
y=np.random.randint(10,size=(20,1))
class mymodel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(mymodel,self).__init__()
    self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(10,return_state=True)
    self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)
  def call(self,input):
    print('hi')
    x=self.l1(input)
    # tf.print(x[0],x[1],x[2])
    x=self.l2(x[0])
    return x
model =mymodel()
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
model.fit(x,y)
```

When I run the code above I get 2 hi printed out.There is only 1 epoch and within that epoch 1 batch(batch size being 20) in this example then why is call method getting called twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related: [tf.print() vs Python print vs tensor.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469673/tf-print-vs-python-print-vs-tensor-eval)

The Python `print` inserted inside the call function will only be executed the first time, when the graph is built underneath. The second call is triggered by the TF eager execution, again only the first time (if you run `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` before `model.fit` you will see only one printed `hi`).

**However**, if you run `model.fit` a second time (and a third, ...) you will notice that nothing gets printed. This is because, once the graph has been built, the forward pass does not execute the `call` function anymore. If you want to print something related to each execution of the forward pass, you should use instead `tf.print("hi")`. You will notice that, this way, one and only one print happens each eopch in `model.fit`.

Comment: So, tf.print('hi') keeps on printing hi on each model.fit call because tf.print becomes a part of the graph itself. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: precisely! tf.print becomes a node in the graph, and in TF2 it gets ran everytime